# Где-то ошибка в коде Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Не могу понять почему не работает код.Именно наследование. Прошу не просто написать ответ, а и кратко объяснить, чтобы подобные вопросы больше не возникали!

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, name, number_count):
        self.name = name
        self.number_count = number_count
        self.count_condition = 0.0
        self.valid_count = 328475

    def showCount(self, number_count):
        if self.number_count == self.valid_count:
            return round(self.count_condition, 1)
        else:
            return "Wrong count number!"

    def addMoney(self, number_count, money_count):
        if self.number_count == self.valid_count:
            self.count_condition += money_count
        else:
            return "Error!"

    def minusMoney(self, number_count, money_count):
        if self.number_count == self.valid_count:
            self.count_condition -= money_count
        else:
            return "Error!"


class InterestAccount(BankAccount):
    def addInterest(self, procent):
        if self.count_condition > 0:
            return (BankAccount.count_condition / 100) * self.procent


myCount = BankAccount("One", 328475)
myCount.addMoney(328475, 45.5)
print(myCount.showCount(328475))
myCount.minusMoney(328475, 1.3)
print(myCount.showCount(328475))
myProcent = InterestAccount("One", 328475)
print(myProcent.addInterest(7))
```

Вывод :

```
45.5
44.2
None
```

Comment: А как должно работать?

Comment: должно высчитывать процент

class InterestAccount(BankAccount):
    def addInterest(self, procent):
        if self.count_condition > 0:
            return (BankAccount.count_condition / 100) * self.procent

и возвращать. А возвращает None. То есть данные с одного экземпляра и возвращать в другой с изменениями.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать поля `count_condition` и `valid_count` статическими в классе `BankAccount`

Comment: результат тот же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда функция или метод возвращает None? Когда нету return, как я понял, поэтому у тебя None выводит. А условие не срабатывает, потому что `count_condition = 0.0` Потому что ты наследуешь все атрибуты класса, но не атрибуты какого-то конкретного объекта с изменениями. Поэтому тебе стоит включить свой init в класс дочерний, то есть переопределить его, а там уже вписать это всё. Или по-другому (скинул код):

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, name, number_count):
        self.name = name
        self.number_count = number_count
        self.count_condition = 0.0


    def showCount(self, number_count):
        if self.number_count == number_count:
            return round(self.count_condition, 1)
        else:
            return "Wrong count number!"


    def addMoney(self, number_count, money_count):
        if self.number_count == number_count:
            self.count_condition += money_count
        else:
            return "Error!"


    def minusMoney(self, number_count, money_count):
        if self.number_count == number_count:
            self.count_condition -= money_count
        else:
            return "Error!"


class InterestAccount(BankAccount):
    def addInterest(self, procent):
        if self.count_condition > 0:
            print('hi')
            return (self.count_condition / 100) * procent


myCount = BankAccount("Daniil", 1)

myCount.addMoney(1, 45.5)
print(myCount.showCount(1))

myCount.minusMoney(1, 1.3)
print(myCount.showCount(1))

myProcent = InterestAccount('Daniil', 1)
print(myProcent.count_condition)
print(myProcent.addInterest(45.5, 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, нужно что то вроде

```
class One:
    class_var = 0

    def modify(self, value):
        self.__class__.class_var = value


class Two(One):
    def read(self):
        return self.__class__.class_var

one = One()
one.modify(42)
two = Two()
print(two.read()) # 42
```

Т.Е. мало определить поле как принадлежащее классу, нужно обращаться к нему соответственно. Иначе поле, принадлежащее `self` перекроет доступ к полю класса.

```
class One:
    class_var = 0

    def modify(self, value):
        self.class_var = value


class Two(One):
    def read(self):
        return self.class_var

one = One()
one.modify(42)
two = Two()
print(two.read()) # 0
```

Comment: что-то вроде этого, но как конкретно в моем примере получить доступ на self.count_condition, потому как в твоем примере мне не совсем все понятно

Comment: Как то так: [ideone](http://ideone.com/LejvBE)

Comment: а сможешь вкратце объяснить, что делает метод ___class__?

Comment: почитать об этом можно, например, на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114576/)